# HTML transform builder for client or server side?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've started using [json2html](http://json2html.com/) but I have a fairly large piece of HTML that I need to transform.

Is there a better method of creating this transform other then using the transform builder via the site?

Are there client or server side tools that can take a piece of HTML with variables and create the required transform that gets passed to javascript?

Here is an example of what the transform would look like:

HTML:

```
<div id='${id}'>
<span>First Name: ${fname}</span>
<span>Last Name: ${lname}</span>
<span>Age: ${age}</span>
</div>
```

Transform:

```
{"tag":"div","id":"${id}","children":[
{"tag":"span","html":"First Name: ${fname}"},
{"tag":"span","html":"Last Name: ${lname}"},
{"tag":"span","html":"Age: ${age}"}
]}
```

Comment: mustache, handlebars, knockout, there are many html+json template packages out there...

Comment: @dandavis I've looked at those.  What I need is very basic, just something to create the transform based on my HTML

Comment: in that case, mustache, jq templates, or just the routine you are using are all pretty simple.

Comment: This tool may help you: https://github.com/gregory80/fastFrag